# Adding text to a dynamic text field randomly in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

i have a text field called Moneytxt and i want it so when u click on a box it somtimes adds 200 and somtimes adds 100 ( also i would like it to add up in numerical value example: if it adds 100 and it has 200 it equals 300 not 200100) . I also have penniestxt where sometimes it adds 30 and somtimes it adds 40.

this is the code (box getting added is not included or addeventlistener)

```
public function boxclick(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var _box:Box=event.currentTarget as Box;
            logtxt.appendText(" You collected the box");
            Moneytxt.random.appendText("100")
            Moneytxt.random.appendText("200")
            penniestxt.random.appendText("40")


            boxAmount--;

            removeChild(_box);
        }
```

Comment: This question is missing a lot of details. First of all, what's Moneytxt? Second, what's penniestxt? Third, what's boxAmount? Please provide a simplified version of your class/mxml that includes these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appendText method does exactly what it says--it appends text to the end of the text in the textfield--which is why you're getting "200100" instead of "300.

To have the numbers add together you need to keep the money amount stored as a Number or int.

```
var money:int = 0;
money += 100;
money += 200;
Moneytxt.text = String(money);
```

Note that you'll probably have to cast the value to a String when you assign it to the text field text.

To do the random value, you can use `Math.random()`. It returns a number between 0 and 1. You can use that value to determine if you add 100 or 200.

```
var money:int = 0;
public function boxclick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var randVal:Number = Math.random();
    if(randVal >= 0.5){
        money += 100;
    } else {
        money += 200;
    }

   Moneytxt.text = String(money);
}
```

Comment: how would i change likelihoods and how would i add extra numbers like 300.

Comment: By checking for different ranges in `randVal`. In my example I'm checking if the random number is greater or equal to 0.5, so you get a 50/50 chance. If you want a 75% chance, check for `randVal` being greater than 0.25.